# put a save code in a text box and than change a variable to that save code

Tags: javascript, html

I'm back and i tried it but is doesn't work anyone that can help??? i have already put in the save mechanism.
(i had to add extra text so this has nothing to do with the script itself)

this is the code that i used to test the save mechanism.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="point();">points</button>
<button onclick="upgrade()">upgrade</button>
<script language="javascript">
var pointcount = 0;
var totalcliks = 0;
var upgrades = 0;
function point() {
pointcount++;
totalcliks++;
}
function upgrade() {
upgrades++;
pointcount--;
}
function load() {
  var testerload = document.getElementById("savecodetextbox").value;
  document.getElementById("saveshow").innerHTML = testerload;
}
var pointcounterclock = setInterval(function() {pointcounter()},100);
    function pointcounter(){
    document.getElementById("points-screen").innerHTML = pointcount+" points";
    document.getElementById("clicktotal").innerHTML = totalcliks+" totalcliks";
    document.getElementById("savecode").innerHTML = totalcliks+"a"+ pointcount+"a"+ upgrades;
    }
let savecode = "1a1a1"; //grab the input for savecode here
let codes = savecode.split("a");
if(codes.length == 3){ //verify the length is correct
    totalcliks = codes[1];
    updates = codes[2];
    pointcount = codes[3];
}
</script>
<h3 id="points-screen"></h3>
<h3 id="clicktotal"></h3>
<h3 id="savecode"></h3>
<textarea name="text_area" id="savecodetextbox" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea> <button onclick="load()">load</button>
<h3 id="saveshow"></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please consider adding a code example, what you expect to achieve and what are you getting to make your question more clear.

Comment: @namelivia do i need to put in the whole code or just the bit that creates the save code

Comment: @QBsmartguy just the code needed to reproduce your problem please.

Comment: @MarkBaijens thats the problem I'm pretty new to them (coding by itself) and don't know how to make a script for this problem

Comment: @QBsmartguy Np, we all had to start at some point. Have a read in the following link. Should help a lot. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MarkBaijens is this better???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to alter your save code so I don't have to confuse you with regular expressions or funky splits:

```
document.getElementById("savecode").innerHTML = totalcliks+"a"+ pointcount+"a"+ upgrades;
```

Which means your save code could look something like: **4a6a9**

Do a simple split:

```js
let savecode = "4a5a6"; //grab the input for savecode here

let codes = savecode.split("a");

if(codes.length  == 3){ //verify the length is correct
    totalcliks = codes[0];
    upgrades = codes[1];
    pointcount = codes[2];
}
```

As for implementing the variables, reload the game after

Comment: sorry maybe its just me but when i try to put this code in mine it totally breaks everything   *ahh sorry i made a typo in my new scrip tanks man it really helped

Comment: have i done something wrong here because it doesn't work (i feel like a noob)

Comment: I'm unable to answer that because you don't have your code posted.

Comment: its there now (sorry I'm a little bit slow)

Comment: is there anything wrong with the script (sorry if I'm annoying)

Comment: @QBsmartguy, in your example code you have the savecode as "testerload" but your variables are numbers so it should be like: 4a6a9

Comment: @QBsmartguy I updated my code, I had a typo. But you also changed an important part of my code. The number in the brackets [], must start with 0, then 1 then 2. Splitting a string creates an array and arrays are zero based so the first value in an array is at position 0 not 1.

Comment: ok sorry i didn't even notice i changed it and thanks for the change in ur script

Comment: o @imvain2 is there any possible way that the code that u made could work with what is in the textbook???

Comment: ok so i used ur code in the big real version (u got a shoutout) but it now really breaks things should i start a new question???

Comment: @QBsmartguy, I would accept my answer, hit the up arrow and then ask a new question. That way you can provide the updated issue since I'm sure it has something to do with other code in the full version.

Comment: @invain2 (sorry but I'm new to stack overflow) what do u mean with: "hit the up arrow and then ask a new question. That way you can provide the updated issue"??

Comment: @QBsmartguy, next to my answer you should see a checkmark and an arrow pointing up above the 0. The checkmark accepts the answer and the up arrow says the answer was useful.